# Can I directly call the overloaded parenthesis on my object?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Assume I have overloaded () let's say to return an integer, I am writing some method of my class and I need to call the overloaded () on the current object,

Can I write say 3 + (i,j) instead of 3 + (*this)(i,j) ?

Comment: No. You can't do that

Comment: Why isn't showing a compiler error ? does (i,j) have some other meaning ?

Comment: (i,j) will evaluate to j

Answer (score 8):

You can't say

```
3 + (i,j)
```

but you can say

```
3 + operator()(i, j)
```

or

```
3 + (*this)(i, j)
```

Comment: Well, you can say `3 + (i,j)`. It just doesn't quite do what you want :)